# Setting SharePoint Group as SPGroup Owner using PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, groups

How can i set existing SharePoint Group as Group Owner (instead of SPUser, set SPGroup as owner) using PowerShell at the time of creation of new Group?

Answer (score 0):

```
#Get the SPWeb
$web = Get-SPWeb http://url_to_web

#Get the Group
$group = $web.SiteGroups["Target Group Name"]
$existingGroup = $web.SiteGroups["Existing Group Name"]

#Assign that user as the owner
$group.Owner = $existingGroup

#Update the Group
$group.Update()
```

Ideally this should be enough for it. If doesn't work, type cast $existingGroup group as a user. and assign to the `$group.Owner`

I am assuming both groups are already created, and you are updating permissions now.

PS: It is not tested since I don't have test environment available right now to test it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code,

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell

$web = Get-SPWeb URL
$GroupName = "GroupName"
$Ownergroup = $web.SiteGroups["OwnerGroupName"]
$Description = "Enter the description"
$member = $web.SiteUsers["domain\username"]
$web.SiteGroups.Add($GroupName, $Ownergroup, $member, $Description)
$web.Update();

Remove-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
```

**Note:**

1. Please, change the URL of the web
2. Please, change the "OwnerGroupName" to your respective group name.
3. Instead of user, you can also assign a group for members, change the "domain\username"

Comment: Please feel free to mark it as answer, if it has helped you because it might help someone in future too :) . For more information, please drop a comment,

Answer (score 0):

If you want it in SPO, you can do it via PNP PowerShell

## Connect to your SharePoint site

Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://your-sharepoint-site-url" -Credentials (Get-Credential)

## Retrieve the SharePoint group that you want to set as owner

$sharePointGroup = Get-PnPGroup -Identity "Your SharePoint Group Name"

## Retrieve the SPGroup (SharePoint group) that you want to update

$spGroup = Get-PnPGroup -Identity "Your SPGroup Name"

## Set the SharePoint group as the owner of the SPGroup

$spGroup.SetOwner($sharePointGroup)

## Update the SPGroup

$spGroup.Update()

## Execute the pending operations

Invoke-PnPQuery

Additional resources from [here](https://tipsbybits.com/sharepoint/powershell-sharepoint-group-operations/)